# Customizing Attachment control on TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Is it possible to add new column to Attachment control in TFS?
Default columns are "Name", "Size", "Date Attached" and "Comments".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to customise the columns.